# Redshift system tables return only the results for current database. How to make cross db queries?

Tags: amazon-redshift

`SVV_TABLE_INFO` shows data for only the current database. How to get the data for all the databases when querying system tables?

```
# SELECT DATABASE, SCHEMA from svv_table_info where database='db2' limit 1;
 database | schema
----------+--------
(0 rows)
```

At present, I need to login with the same user but to a different database to get SVV_TABLE_INFO for that database.

On logging to db2, the above query shows data.

Do you know how to do it?

Comment: possibly see https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/10/announcing-cross-database-queries-for-amazon-redshift-preview/ and follow instructions? you may need to be on ra3 nodes?

Comment: simple answer: Not possible, long answer: as @JonScott suggests, use cross data query or run the query directly on the database.